# Weird behavior of ternary operator

Tags: java, string, ternary-operator

I have weird situation which I cannot explain after debugging. I want to set label text with that pattern:

POI: "replacement"

Replacement depends on ternary operation which looks like this:

```
label.setText("POI: " + requestItem.getPoi() != null ? requestItem.getPoi() : "#####")
```

`requestItem.getPoi()` returns type of String and I want to check if it returns String or null. If null I want to set '#####'.

Problem is with `requestItem.getPoi() != null ? requestItem.getPoi() : "#####"`

When I evaluate this value in debugger when requestItem.getPoi() returns null debugger throws "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from String to void".

Anyone has an idea what is wrong with this operation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by operator precedence, you must surround the ternary expression between parentheses. Try this:

```
"POI: " + (requestItem.getPoi() != null ? requestItem.getPoi() : "#####")
```

Comment: Óscar López was faster than me :D but i have a little bit of helpt for you, if you try to debug things like this, you can try to extract things into variables like `String poiToPrint = requestItem.getPoi() != null ? requestItem.getPoi() : "#####"`. SO then you'll see the value of it. (Also this little snippet solves your problem as well :) )